# Native Americans + inverted Manifest Destiny

Tags: science-based, alternate-history, domestication

I was reading a graphic novel [Black Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Science_(comics)) where the characters come upon a parallel universe where [advanced](https://gjalmont.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/black-science-how-to-fall-forever-v1-2014-page-30.jpg) [Native](http://images.mobilism.org/?dm=8VH9) [American](http://mylardreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/BlackScience03-pg5-6b52d.jpg) Tribes invaded Europe. An inverse manifest destiny, if you will.

#### Suppose:

In 1492 a Native American 'explorer' makes landfall in Europe/Africa. This explorer returns home with fruits, slaves, thus kickstarting a campaign to invade/colonize Eurasia+Africa

## How would a Native American nation (or civilization) develop (technologically, culturually, and sociologically) from to achieve this historical event?

#### Considerations:

1. Only North American Native American tribes and cultures are allowed. Incans, Mayans, and Aztecs will be the subject of other questions.
2. I am interested in how a native american civilization could've developed to this point. The consequences afterwards of Native Americans invading Europe will be covered in a separate question.
3. Feel free to implement Leif Erikson's journey however you like or not all. Leif Erikson may be ignored and left to the annals of history much like modern history, or become integral as in @Will's answer.

#### Rules

1. Please use historical revisionism and science where possible.
2. **No Magic.**
3. Native Americans did not have horses.
4. Native Americans [domesticated animals](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/200teb/did_native_americans_have_any_domesticated/) (Llamas, Dogs, [Bobcats](http://mentalfloss.com/article/65977/native-americans-might-have-domesticated-bobcats-2000-years-ago), [Turkeys](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/53dq4k/native-americans-domesticated-turkeys-hundreds-of-years-before-thanksgiving)) but did not have nearly as many available animals to domesticate as Europe, especially with regards to beasts of burden.
5. Native Americans did have agriculture (corn and other fruits and vegetables) and were familiar with farming techniques.
6. The Americas were and are rich in resources such as food, minerals, animals, etc.
7. With respect to pathogens, Native Americans would still remain vulnerable to many European diseases. That said, if someone were to explain how Native Americans could domesticate animals to an industrial degree, '[America Pox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEYh5WACqEk)' would be game.

EDIT: Since the original question was too broad, I've limited the scope of North American Native Americans and the development of a civilization to the age of exploration only.

EDIT 2: To address JBH's comment: I am aware of [literature](https://www.edge.org/conversation/jared_diamond-why-did-human-history-unfold-differently-on-different-continents-for-the) that posits why native americans did not develop as fast as Eurasians. That said, there is little literature that explains how native americans could have developed faster than Eurasians. With respect to World Building, if we assume it were possible, how then could native americans develop in such a manner. That is the underlying subject I'm looking to answer (via worldbuilding). Since this is a science based question, I do expect some science to be used, but citations are not neccesary.

Comment: [A recent question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/100878/what-are-the-minimal-questions-i-need-to-answer-for-muslims-and-vikings-to-have) that appears to only be asking for basic information for alternate history research was put on hold for being too broad, but might be reopened if what is being sought is narrowed.  This question, likewise, is to broad because it's asking us to rewrite history, which is too much for this site.

Comment: It would take the angel of death killing everyone in the Old World. There is [plenty](https://www.amazon.com/Guns-Germs-Steel-Fates-Societies/dp/0393317552) written about why the Old World was so far ahead of the New. To change history this completely isn't a matter of one or two tweaks. Frankly, I think it is impossible, give your rules. I'm voting to close this as opinion based.

Comment: The CGP Grey video 'America Pox' video you have linked in the question is your own bane, because moving onto advanced metallurgy, coal production and industrialization will be difficult when growing your food takes all day. In the tech tree, all, atleast most, of the requirements of one stage must be fulfilled before you can move on to the nest stage i.e. Agricultural Revolution to Industrial Revolution. The Americans had yet to outsource the field work to non-human labourers, in this case domesticated animals, so they simply would not have the time to get on with mechanised labour.

Comment: Although you could have that intellectual kid, son of the rich merchant/noble, who feels for the poor and is fascinated about everything, and after discovering the combustible of coal, coal mines, and ordering many metallic apparatus, leaves the steam engine as his inheritance to the continent's people, remembered for all of eternity as *The Inventor*.

Comment: What metal? By 1492, metallurgy had just gotten to the bronze level in Central/South America, but not sufficient to have widespread, common use of basic implements instead of adornments or decoration. In terms of metal technology, the Americas were running about 6000 years or more behind the Old World.

Comment: @JBH : I would disagree with respect to historical revisionism; but, I do see you point on broadness. What if I were to limit the question to only one particular culture of Native Americans (say Mayans) and limit historical revisions only to that culture  --Europe's history remains unchanged.

Comment: @VaradMahashabde the level of urbanisation of the Azteс Empire prior to the Spanish conquest was at least 60% (which is comparable with Europe's 54% in 1891). The land was so fertile and irrigation systems were so advanced that in some places it was possible to harvest 7 crops annually. [Recent research](http://www.public.asu.edu/~mesmith9/1-CompleteSet/MES-05-SciAm-.pdf) also shows that life in Aztec Empire was not as primitive and mind-numbing as some people tend to believe.

Comment: It's still too broad.  Please remember, the Stack Exchange websites are not designed for a discussion or to be a forum.  They are one-question, one-right-answer.  You have not proposed a question that can have one right answer.  Basically, you're fishing for ideas.  We're happy to do that on a small scale ("what boat technology would the Mayans have needed to cross the Atlantic?") but on the scale of history, it's simply too broad.

Comment: I like the idea, but I can't vote to re-open until we get a specific question.

Comment: Got it. I'll update this later today when I get out of work.

Comment: Update: I've editted the question to narrow it down to North American Natives and only towards technological, cultural, and sociological development to achieve the equivalent of Christopher Columbus. If that still appears too broad, please explain why so I may further refine this. Thank you everyone!

Comment: You know, I'm going to vote to recommend this question be reopened.  It's actually quite a bit more interesting now that it reads, "if the NA natives had found the old country first... how would that have affected their people upon their return?"  That's not rewriting history, that's looking at how knowledge of a more advanced culture could affect a less advanced cutlure, and I believe that's narrow enough to answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @JBH (Also, OP.) I don't see how this isn't still _too broad_ or _primarily opinion-based_. According to OP's second consideration, s/he wants to know how a nation developed in terms of social, cultural, and technological constructs. We frequently close that as one of the two reasons I listed. Is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Frostfyre, you could be right.  The rules say "Effects of events or world elements, including biology, technology and magic, on specific aspects of that world's societies, cultures, and environment."  I suppose it's a question of what a "specific aspect" is.  Would "technologically, culturally, and socialogically" be to broad?  Would only one of them be too broad?  As written, it feels answerable to me without writing a book.  (And 99.9% of the questions we answer are "primarily opinion-based."  Especially questions about magic.  That limitation doesn't help us as much as we think.)

Comment: This is still too broad, but--as this is something I've spent a fair amount of time looking into--imagine what would have happened if they'd domesticated caribou before crossing over from Russia.

Comment: Plague (or any other European disease)  in north america is the conclusion I come to when thinking about NA coming into contact with EU.

Answer (score 1):

The sophisticated culture of the [Mound Builders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinland) comes into contact with Vikings at their outpost in [Vinland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinland) around the year 1000 in what is now eastern Canada. The Mound Builders have copper technology, agriculture, long distance trade routes and enough surplus population to build the mounds that are their legacy.

The Mound Builders invite the Vikings to visit their lands further south and strike up a productive interaction - the visiting Norsemen find these lands more pleasant than the far north.  Additionally the Mound Builders are more civilized and physically more attractive to the Norse than the Inuit were. The Norse are treated respectfully and well by the civilized Mound Builder people.  The native Americans realize they have a lot to learn from the vikings and proceed to learn it from the original vikings they encounter as well as those Norsemen who follow, settle, and begin to interbreed over the ensuing 150 years.

Within 2 generations, the coastal Indians who have learned Norse metalworking and shipbuilding tech (and who have begun to breed horses!) have conquered their neighbors and imposed a "Pax Romana" on the formerly squabbling groups of the interior and southerly coast.  Population increases during the following prosperity.

An effective central government modeled along the lines of [Cahokia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahokia) together with population pressure and encouragement from Vikings finally led to construction of a fleet which sailed East and make landfall in Ireland and then England in 1380.  The descendants of the Mound Builders / Norsement were [giants](https://books.google.com/books?id=8FgoDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=giant+indians+smithsonian&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7sOnrj6zYAhUBSmMKHVxBD50Q6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=giant%20indians%20smithsonian&f=false) and the Europeans - all devout Christians and just recovering from the effects of continent-wide plague - received them as [Nephilim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephilim) sent by God to create a new order.  Ready to take on this role, the Native Americans convert to a hybrid Christianity incorporating aspects of their old religions and Norse religion.  At the same time, epidemic syphilis spreads from these new invaders across the continent, and the Great Pox further damages a population as yet unrecovered from the Black Plate.

The giant-led Native Americans take another 100 years in England, receiving shiploads of colonists during this time and reinforcing their presence.  By 1400 they begin their spread into continental Europe.

Comment: The OP has edited his question to make it less broad.  Will this affect your answer?

Comment: The thing that feels gross about this answer is that, instead of doing it on their own, the Native Americans need some white people to show them how it's done.

Comment: @Azuaron Nothing gross about learning technology from more advance people. You will find history is all about that. Even the great "white people" had to learn their technology from the arabs in the middle ages.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. Way to ignore the current cultural context and the fact that this is made up.

Comment: @Azuaron What cultural context? We are talking about an civilization learning from another and then using it as their own. It really doesn't matter if the tech comes from "white people" or maybe you want the Chinese to come across the Pacific. The simple thing is that North America was not very technologically advance and advances in tech are historically from getting it from somewhere else then applying it to your own culture and making small advances yourself.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. The context of writing this story _right now_, with our history of white people _oppressing; killing; and appropriating or erasing the culture of Native Americans_. And now we have a Worldbuilding exercise for how to make Native Americans (historically) technologically superior, a problem with innumerable solutions, and this solution is, "Clearly they can't do it on their own, have white people show them how"? It's gross because it's racist and privileged. Bonus points for the invading Native Americans "half"-converting to Christianity. Because it wasn't _already_ messed up enough.

Comment: @Azuaron So you just want some power fantasy for Native Americans and say they don't need no white man? Europe was a center of power during the colonial ages largely because they were able to learn so much from the exchanges during the crusades and trade with the Arab world. Does the white man care that the gun he shoots was originally invented in China and the astronomy he used to navigate the ocean was once translated from Arabic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70965/discussion-between-azuaron-and-a-c-a-c).

Comment: *"I've limited the scope of North American Native Americans and the development of a civilization to the age of exploration only"* - If you were to re-edit the Question-Title and first paragraph to reflect this editorial-comment, it would help a bit. "How Would they develop" - given the uncertainty of motives, world politics and power in your question, still somewhat too-broad really. (From review)